# Shiny: sep argument in sliderInput throws error

Tags: r, slider, shiny

Hopefully this is something easy and stupid.  I'm trying to get a slider input to pick a year.  It works, but the slide shows values like `"1,997"` instead of `"1997"`.  Annoying.  So I found on [this page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html) that there is a `sep=","` argument defaulted on sliderInput.

But then when I put `sep=""` into my code, it breaks the app and says
`Error in sliderInput("year", "Which Year?", value = 2000, sep = "", min = 1984,  : 
  unused argument (sep = "")`

Any thoughts?  Here is the complete sidebar.  It was working before I added the `sep`

`sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput('year', 'Which Year?', value = 2000, sep = "", 
                    min = 1984, max = 2015, step = 1,),
        h4('albums on both lists:'),
        verbatimTextOutput("winners"),
        h4('chart-toppers that the critics snubbed:'),
        verbatimTextOutput("loser")
    ),`

Comment: why do u have a comma after `step = 1`

Comment: just a typo.  It does the same thing when I delete the comma though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(sidebarPanel(sliderInput('year', 'Which Year?', value = 2000, sep = "", min = 1984, max = 2015, step = 1)))
server = (function(input, output) {})
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: That's the same thing I tried.  I even copy/pasted yours to make sure it wasn't a typo.  Is it something buggy, or has the` sep=` option been deprecated?  I don't get it.

Comment: I'm on shiny version 0.12.0.9002, did you update to 0.12.2 maybe thats causing the issue. Updates can be found [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/shiny/NEWS)

Comment: @seth127 I believe this is an issue of shiny version. I suggest you upgrade your R packages before trying again: `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`

Comment: I just updated to shiny_0.12.2 and that fixed it.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to shiny_0.12.2 and that fixed it. Thanks for all the help.